# Wix CustomAction Binary SourceFile not found

Tags: binary, wix, action

```
<Binary Id="binUpdate" SourceFile="c:\xxx\Update.exe"/>

<CustomAction Id="Update" BinaryKey="binUpdate" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="c:\xxx" />
```

When I build a Wix project with the above custom action, it complains that "The system cannot find the file 'C:\xxx\Update.exe".

This update.exe is deployed by the same msi. So, how do I make Wix to ignore the fact that the file does not exist on my build machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the executable in the same folder as your "Product.wxs" file and doing something like this...

```
<CustomAction Id="Update" FileKey="Update.exe" ExeCommand="param1" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncNoWait" />;
```

[Here is a link at codeprojects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WiXTricks.aspx#_Toc245109716)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful by making this the selected answer or comment if it was not.